# i need sbt 0.11.2 to build the mongo auth app for lift

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift, sbt

For some reason sbt bails on .11.3 when working with the mongodb-record auth project, and it seems to me that's the only version i can download from the git site.

Answer (score 8):

The idiomatic way is to specify sbt version in `build.properties` as

```
sbt.version=0.11.2
```

But since group id in 0.11.3 was [changed](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Changes) from `org.scala-tools.sbt` to `org.scala-sbt`, sbt can't resolve older versions. But you still can manually download older version of launcher from [typesafe repo](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/).

Comment: Why oh why would they do such a thing without documenting it or offering backwards compatibility?

Comment: Oh my god!! Thank you thank you thank you! I've been trying to solve this issue for the entire day! Googled 50 different variations of the problem until I reached this one, which doesn't have exactly the right keywords for the general problem.
I didn't face this with mongo, I was trying to run the Scala School twitter example of searchbird and one of the plugins requires sbt 0.11.2, trying to change the build properties didn't work for the exact reason you said of the group id.

And I couldn't find older versions of sbt anywhere. THANK YOU!