# Trying to build kestrel using a sbt 0.11.2 jar

Tags: scala, sbt, kestrel

So I downloaded sbt 0.11.2 because kestrel only works with that version, I am also running java 6.

So I downloaded 0.11.2 from here: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/0.11.2/sbt-launch.jar

I created a folder for the sbt-launch.jar for 0.11.2 like:
/sbt/0.11.2/sbt-launch.jar

I then created a .sh file that will launch that specific version of sbt.

Now once I launch sbt using my .sh file, I get this error.

My project isn't even referencing the sbt-idea plugin, so it seems to be mixed up with my current version of sbt maybe?

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#testing_2.9.1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#compiler-interface;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_8_1;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_8_0;0.11.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-tools.sbt#precompiled-2_9_0;0.11.2 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.4.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/Users/blah/.sbt/plugins/}default-bfa0a6/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.4.0: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Reference: it seems 0.11.2 is old and has a different format: [i need sbt 0.11.2 to build the mongo auth app for lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516610/i-need-sbt-0-11-2-to-build-the-mongo-auth-app-for-lift)

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me get this to build correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `sbt-idea` plugin.

I've checked the kestrel and doesn't seem it's using the plugin, so I bet you have installed it globally or added it yourself.

Since the plugins are only compatible with the specific version of SBT. I think you'll have to disable that plugin or downgrade it to the version, which supports the SBT version you're using.

Check if you have the plugin defined in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` and not in `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`.

However if you're using Idea 13.1 and latest Scala plugin, the Idea can import the projects directly, so you shouldn't really need the plugin.

Comment: I have it in:  ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt   Not sure how it got there, but why is it conflicting with my other sbt version?  thanks!

Comment: I think in older versions it was the place to keep it, and then later it was changed to the `~/.sbt/<version>/plugins/build.sbt`

Comment: Now I'm getting this error ```[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/twitter/scala-parent-292/0.0.4/scala-parent-292-0.0.4.jar```

Comment: Well seems like it's more a problem of connectivity than SBT itself, try to access the file with a browser and it will fail as well (at least does for me)

Comment: Seems that `http://scala-tools.org` is no longer serving jars, you may need to declare another resolvers.